# Path to assets folder, from RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, carrierwave

I am trying to test a carrierwave image upload to a model, using RSpec / capybara / Factory girl for Rails.

This specific test tests the validation that an image should be present.

At the moment, I have this code:

```
it "should accept a spotlight record with spotlight info" do
  feature = create :feature, spotlight: true, spotlight_description: "description", spotlight_image: File.open(Rails.root.join "/app/assets/shopstar_logo_stamp.png")
  expect(feature).to be_valid
end
```

But somehow the image isn't detected, and I get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Feature validations should accept a spotlight record with spotlight info
     Failure/Error: feature = create :feature, spotlight: true, spotlight_description: "description", spotlight_image: File.open(Rails.root.join "/app/assets/shopstar_logo_stamp.png")
     Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory - /app/assets/shopstar_logo_stamp.png
     # ./spec/models/feature_spec.rb:32:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/models/feature_spec.rb:32:in `open'
     # ./spec/models/feature_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I specify a path to an image in assets and use it for testing?


Or alternatively, what is a better way of testing a carrierwave image upload?

Comment: hi Marco - did my answer help you?  If so please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an acceptance test/integration test you'll actually want to do it from the users perspective using capybara like this:

```
feature 'user uploads image' do
 scenario '#Image' do
    count = ImageModel.count
    visit new_image_path

    attach_file('css_selector_here', File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/support/herst.jpg'))
    click_button('Submit')

    expect(page).to have_content('Image uploaded successfully!')
    expect(ImageModel.count).to eq(count + 1)
  end
end
```

If you're after a unit test, do something like this with `FactoryGirl` in `spec/factories/factory.rb`

```
Factory.define :feature do |f|
  f.spotlight true
  f.spotlight_description "description"
  f.spotlight_image { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'support', 'feature', 'images', 'shopstar_logo_stamp.jpg')) }
end
```

now in your unit test you can run your test:

```
it "should accept a spotlight record with spotlight info" do
  feature = create :feature
  expect(feature).to be_valid
end
```

Comment: It's actually a model test. Sorry if there's a lack of clarity as to what i'm asking.. I'm new to testing